# ChromeDriver blocks and does not fail after unexpected Alert box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running selenium-server-standalone-2.17.0 (for IE and Firefox) and ChromeDriver 18.0.1022.0 (standalone) on a test box (Windows 7 64bit) which I use to run Java selenium tests against.

For some reason, when running my tests against ChromeDriver, the first time it encounters an unexpected Alert box, it blocks idefinitely and the ChromeDriver log says

```
WARNING: Executing: executeScript
```

I configured ChromeDriver using the guide http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver and set the timeout of all the drivers with

```
webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Update:**
I figured out how to initialize the remote ChromeDriver in a clean way with

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.15:4444/wd/hub"); 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
Webdriver chromeDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);
```

this ran best with the URL pointing to a selenium-server running chromedriver in a child process. You can make selenium-server run the ChromeDriver by starting it like this:

```
java -jar C:\selenium-server.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe
```

I still have the same problem with Chrome getting stuck at the unexpected Alert box, but the selenium log gave me at bit more info:

```
INFO - Done: /session/1328623219287/element/253/click
INFO - Executing: [execute script: return !!document['readyState'];, []] at URL: /session/1328623219287/execute)
```

Still have no idea what is causing this... can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I initialize ChromeDriver:

```
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, 
"PathToWhereChromeDriverIsAvailable"); 
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
ChromeDriver cd = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

With the `Alert()` i have just plain guess - probably it hangs out while executing the script - so basically you are not waiting for page to load, but for script to end executing. However, I do not have solution for this...

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try and report back

Comment: I don't really understand this "PathToWhereChromeDriverIsAvailable". I run the ChromeDriver and the Chrome browser on a remote machine, so I just need a java object to relay the selenium/webdriver commands to "192.168.1.15:9515" (for example) where ChromeDriver is listening. It would be really annoying to have to supply the path to the chrome browser on the remote machine, and irrelevant too because the remote ChromeDriver server already knows where to find the Chrome browser.

Comment: For example. My program `chromedriver.exe` is stored at D:\_dev\selenium\chromedriver.exe so in my case I replace PathToWhereChromeDriverIsAvailable with `"D:\_dev\selenium\chromedriver.exe"`

Comment: BTW, you can try to ommit the row `System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, 
"PathToWhereChromeDriverIsAvailable");` because if your program already knows it, you do not have to set this property again :) I just copypasted you my method how do I initialize it :)

Comment: I figured out how to initialize the remote driver in a clean way with `URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.15:4444/wd/hub");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
Webdriver chromeDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);` - this ran best with the URL pointing to a selenium-server running chromedriver in a child process. You can make selenium-server run the ChromeDriver by starting it like this: `java -jar C:\selenium-server.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe`